# Is there a direct URL to download Java JDK updates?

Tags: download, java, updates, url

I have a whole set of machines that are on the other side of a firewall configured to prevent all Javascript from functioning.  All of them (Linux 32 and 64 bit configurations) *must* be updated to Java 6 update 20.  This is a problem given Sun/Oracle's URL redirector and download manager: they simply don't appear or don't work.

Is there a URL to download the JDK updates and bypass the redirect?  Obviously, a yum configuration that would allow for automatic updates would be optimal but I'd be happy to just have the rpm file.

Comment: If you tell us which one you need I upload it to a place and give you a direct link. ;P

Comment: +1 to shiki: that could do the trick, and costs nothing. It wouldn't either be the first time that happens such a thing.

Comment: I appreciate the willingness to help but (A) it's highly unlikely that our firewall would allow us to get to you if we're already killing javascript and (b) I support these machines over the long haul.  It would be great if there were a general purpose long term solution.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, there is no "simple" way to retrieve the JDK (that I know of), only through their complicated links.

JDK update 20:

- [Linux 32bits (rpm)](http://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/VerifyItem-Start/jdk-6u20-linux-i586-rpm.bin?BundledLineItemUUID=vjCJ_hCwQv0AAAEounhnyYgD&OrderID=WCaJ_hCwgAIAAAEorXhnyYgD&ProductID=guBIBe.oc_wAAAEnaDJHqPYe&FileName=/jdk-6u20-linux-i586-rpm.bin)
- [Linux 64bits (rpm)](http://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/VerifyItem-Start/jdk-6u20-linux-x64-rpm.bin?BundledLineItemUUID=bqCJ_hCwOXQAAAEorvZnyYgH&OrderID=mTuJ_hCwQD4AAAEon_ZnyYgH&ProductID=d8tIBe.o6WMAAAEnYDJHqPYe&FileName=/jdk-6u20-linux-x64-rpm.bin)

Comment: Sadly, this appears to not work.  The URL redirection appears to create a single use link.  It may have worked for you but it definitely does not work here, either inside or outside our firewall (whereas the "outside" machines CAN download via the redirector).